# C++ template parameter as member pointer will be efficient way of call-by-reference?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, metaprogramming

```cpp
template<class T, typename... Args>
class Wrapper
{
    // simple way of representing pointer-to-member
    template <class T, class V>
    using mv = V T::*;
public:
    // non-type arguments (which are pointers to member)
    template<mv<T, Args>... Ptrs> 
    static void fun(T* t)
    {
        make_tuple(t->*Ptrs...);
    }
};

// inefficient one
template <typename... Args>
void fun_dynmaic_(Args&... args)
{
    make_tuple(args...);
}

// actual class
class Apple
{
    int a; float b; string c;
public:
    Apple(int a, float b, const string& c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}

    void fun_dynamic()
    {
        fun_dynmaic_(a, b, c);
    }
    void fun_static1()
    {
        make_tuple(a, b, c);
    }
    void fun_static2()
    {
        Wrapper<Apple, int, float, string>::fun<&Apple::a, &Apple::b, &Apple::c>(this);
    }
};
```

I have some job to do on all member variables of some class.

Let's suppose that it is `make_tuple()`, simply.

Here I brought 3 implementations of doing this. 
I'm not sure but after compile optimization and inlining, `fun_static1()` and `fun_static2()` will be compiled into almost same, efficient machine code. It would be like this : take a pointer to `Apple` and use solid offset to access directly on each members.

`fun_dynamic()` works well, but carries all address of variables. So it must be inefficient.

For most case, choosing `fun_static1()` seems to be best. It's simple and fastest. However, in some case I might be in some huge requirement. For example, there are `class Banana, class Orange ...` and the task (which should be done on all members of `Apple, Banana..`) could be very complicated but reusable routine (not just `make_tuple()`). If then, I must need a template.

`fun_static1()` can't be used in that case. If I care runtime performance, I must choose `fun_static2()` over `fun_dynamic()`. Right?

In conclusion,

1. I exploit the fact that pointer to member is `constexpr` and so can be an argument of template.
2. So I can construct a function template that **simulates** `fun_static1()`.
3. Now I don't have to pass actual address of each members. Rather, the instantiated functions will have solid offset and can directly use it.
4. It doesn't waste any runtime resource and doesn't play dangerously with `void*` to calculate member offset.

Am I right? Then should I actually implement `fun_static2()` whenever I seriously care the runtime performance?
(I will never do that but just of curiosity)

**Edit** - If you don't get the necessity of template, just simply think that I want to **reuse** `fun_dynmaic_()` over `Apple`'s members, `Banana`'s and so on. Then implementing `fun_static2()` rather `fun_dynamic()` will be an bothersome but (seems to be) faster solution if there are many variables.

**Edit2** - Three functions are doing exactly same thing : **copy** the **value** of a,b,c and put in a tuple. (and it's just an example)

Comment: Being constexpr and being a valid template argument are not the same thing, although they are related.  Here, it’s simply that pointers to members are valid, but ordinary pointers to member variables are not.

Comment: @DavisHerring What is the example of constexpr that cannot be a template argument?

Comment: Any object of class type (though C++20 will allow certain such objects), or of floating-point type, or that is a pointer not to a complete object with linkage…  But that’s not really the point; 1 is a valid template argument but the value itself is not “constexpr” in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ok, but what's the deal? The idea is to instantiate template with argument of **pointer**, not value. I already agreed on that. At least in this situation pointer to member is always a constexpr and can always be a template argument.

Comment: All I’m doing is encouraging better terminology: there is a difference between a constant expression (a necessary but not sufficient condition for any non-type template argument) and an entity (including a function, which has no value) being `constexpr`.  Also, a pointer is of course itself a value that is not fundamentally different here.